# Why only one item showing outside of foreach loop?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, guzzle

I want to get access to variable(arrays) outside of foreach loop.When i do echo inside foreach loop i'm getting this:

[Reuslt inside foreach roop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve2yd.png)

```
$path='http://localhost:8000/api/devices';
try {
    $device= new Client();

    $answer= $device->request('GET', $path);
    $body = $answer->getBody();
    $status = 'true';
    $message = 'Data found!';
    $final= json_decode($body);

    foreach ($final as $res) {
        $id = $res->clientId;
        echo $id;
    }
```

And outside of loop i'm getting only last item of array:
[Result outside foreachloop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0iZ0.png)

```
$route='http://localhost:8000/api/devices';
try {
    $device= new Client();

    $answer= $client->request('GET', $answer);
    $body = $answer->getBody();
    $status = 'true';
    $message = 'Data found!';
    $final= json_decode($body);

    foreach ($finala $res) {
        $id = $res->clientId;
    }
    echo $id;
```

Comment: that's exactly what should happen. what do you actually want? expected output?

Comment: are the calls per ID, or all lumped together? do the calls in the loop if individually

Comment: what does the callimng code look like?

Comment: See my new answer.Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this :

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $id= $item->clientId;
}
echo $id;
```

So every time, your last `$id` value is erased and get the new current id value.

If you want ALL id, try this :

```
// Create an array
$id_array = array();
foreach ($data as $item) {
    // Add each id value in your array
    $id_array[]= $item->clientId;
}
// Here you can display your array and see that you have all value
var_dump($id_array);
```

Now if you want to `echo` (or use) each id AFTER the foreach loop, you can do :

```
foreach($id_array as $my_id) {
    echo $my_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, So if i want to use all Id   i have to do inside foreach loop ?

Comment: It depends of what you want to do with  them :) But just remember that if you want to make a foreach loop and get ALL value outside, you need to build an array and add each value in (or an other way like string concatenation, again : it depends of what you want to do)

Comment: See my new answer.Pls

Comment: This is my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195704/why-my-second-call-on-url-doesnt-work-laravel-guzzle/51195949?noredirect=1#comment89374790_51195949