# Why my second call on url doesn't work (Laravel,Guzzle)?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

This is a function where i call 2 api, from first i get client_id which i used in second url. Problem is that after i call second url my page is loading without end.

[Page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxgFB.png)

```
public function getDevices(){

        $route='http://localhost:8000/api/devices';

        $device= new Client();
        $answer= $device->request('GET', $route);
        $body = $answer->getBody();
        $status = 'true';
        $message = 'Data found!';
        $final= json_decode($body);

        $id_array = array();
    foreach ($finalas $item) {
        // Add each id value in your array
        $id_array[]= $item->clientId;
    }

foreach($id_array as $my_id) {
 $answer2= $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/api/devices/deviceAvailability/' . $my_id );
 $body2 = $response2->getBody();
 $final2= json_decode($body2);

 }


return view('new.home', ['clients' => $final, 'status'=> $final2]);
```

Comment: Not a solution though I think you could benefit yourself if use $data = $response->json(); and only one loop  for($index=1;$i<sizeof($data);$i++){ $my_id = $data[ index - 1]; }

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
return view('new.home', ['clients' => $final, 'status'=> $final2])
```

is wrong. Because `$final` is decoded variable, maybe `$final` contains several types of variables.

In php, you can not set parameter that contains several types of variables.

Please do like that.

```
return view('new.home', ['clients' => $body, 'status'=> $final2]);
```

That's because json encoded variable is only a string.

I want your result.

Comment: Hey thanks for answer, again same thing it just loading page without end. This is what is inside $data  https://imgur.com/a/pTJdJSd